# Asking for vba codes in switching two dynamic ranges in one combobox

Tags: vba, function, dynamic, combobox, comboboxlist

Dears,

I am looking for vba codes in switching two dynamic ranges in one combobox, i set one range under column A (e.g. 1,2,3,4,5) and another range under column D(a,b,c,d,e).  And there are two command button ("letter" and "number") and one combobox. When i click the "letter" button, the range of the combobox will be letter; when i click the "number" button, the range of the combobox will be number. My codes are below:

```
Private Sub Cmd_letter_Click()
Dim x As String
x = "d1"
numberorletter.Clear
Call numberorletterprocedure
End Sub

Private Sub Cmd_number_Click()
Dim x As String
x = "a1"
numberorletter.Clear
Call numberorletterprocedure
End Sub

Private Sub numberorletterprocedure()
Dim x As String
Dim numberorletter As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = sheet1
Set numberorletter.List = sheet1.Range(x, sheet1.Range(x).End(xlDown)).Value
End Sub
```

However, it don't work, could you let me know which part i made the mistakes?  And how it will look like if it is done by create a function, not procedure?  Thanks!

Comment: Welcome! What do you mean by "it don't work", can you share what is wrong exactly?

Comment: Thanks Peter, and @ Super Symmetry has solved my problem....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
Private Sub Cmd_letter_Click()
Dim x As String
x = "d1"
Call numberorletterprocedure(x)
End Sub

Private Sub Cmd_number_Click()
Dim x As String
x = "a1"
Call numberorletterprocedure(x)
End Sub

Private Sub numberorletterprocedure(x As String)
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Sheet1
'* assuming your combobox name is numberorletter
'* if not change it to the correct name
numberorletter.List = ws.Range(x, ws.Range(x).End(xlDown)).Value
End Sub
```

Comment: Many thanks for your super fast response and help.  Yes and your code works well.  But would you mind also let me know what necessary changes in the codes if i want to use a function instead, but not a subroutine (e.g. numberorletterprocedure in this case)?  Thanks!

Comment: Here you can simply change the keyword `Sub` to `Function` and it will work exactly the same. If you want to know more about the differences between functions and subroutines in VBA have a look at [this](https://www.exceldemy.com/differences-between-subroutine-and-function-in-excel-vba/) article for example.

Comment: Many thanks. Yes and I have tried,  completely what you said.  Since it is not sub anymore, i also try to omit "call" in the code line, and it also work.  By the way, do you think it is necessary to add the code line numberorletter.clear before a function call?

Comment: Not in this case because you're defining the `.List` of your combobox and therefore, the previous `.List` will be cleared implicitly. If, however, you were building your list using `.AddItem` for example, your will need to `.Clear` your combobox to start a new list. Otherwise, you would simply append items to your previously added items.

Comment: Yes and you have answered my question, is there somewhere in this webpage i can mark something here?  I just enter recently and i am new ....sorry